# CSS Positioning. 4 Divs equally divided and placed into 1 parent div

Tags: html, css, user-interface, positioning

There's got to be an easier way.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#main {
  width: 107px;
  height: 107px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#tl, #tr, #bl, #br {
  position: relative;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

#tl {
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}

#tr {
   top: -46px;
   left: 55px;  
}

#bl {
  left: 3px;
  top: -43px;
}

#br {
  top: -92px;
  left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="tl">Top Left</div>
<div id="tr">Top Right</div>
<div id="bl">Bottom Left</div>
<div id="br">Bottom Right</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions?  I'm still trying to learn better styling in order to build nicer GUI's on my web apps.

I just want to place these four divs equally inside of one parent div container.  The four divs are "Top Left", "Top Right", "Bottom Left" and "Bottom Right".

Comment: Can the solution contain external libraries like bootstrap?

Comment: I'm open to that, but it would still be nice to know if there's a pure css solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use `display:flex;` and `flex-wrap:wrap;` on main container and `margin:auto` on childs

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;/* switch box model to integrate padding and borders into size */
}

#main {
  width: 107px;
  height: 107px;
  padding: 2px; /*eventually*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  /* show me */
  background:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 50%, transparent 50%),linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 50%, transparent 50%);
}

#tl, #tr, #bl, #br {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="tl">Top Left</div>
        <div id="tr">Top Right</div>
        <div id="bl">Bottom Left</div>
        <div id="br">Bottom Right</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set each container to 50%, and float them side by side...

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
  <div style="width: 50%; float: left; background-color: red;">1</div>
  <div style="width: 50%; float: left; background-color: green;">2</div>
  <div style="width: 50%; float: left; background-color: orange;">3</div>
  <div style="width: 50%; float: left; background-color: pink;">4</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/908ugcwh/

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would style it like this:

```
<style>

div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#main {
  width: 107px;
  height: 107px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#tl, #tr, #bl, #br {  
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-left:3px;
  float:left;
}

#bl, #br {  
  margin-bottom:3px; 
}

</style>
```

Give it a try. Cheers.

Comment: Just a suggestion: styling general elements as divs - div { border: 2px solid black; } - is not such a good idea, because in the future you might want some divs not to have a black border. Start working with classes.  .blackborderdiv { border: 2px solid black; } - <div id="tl" class="blackborderdiv">Top Left</div>